# Python and Django ,<built-in function id> error function, where is the issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following class:

```
class Income(models.Model):
  income = models.DecimalField()
  date = models.DateField()
```

In my views I have created an algo that give me the possibility to collect all date monthly, like the following:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.year
income = dict()
for year, month, totals in (Income.objects.values_list('date__year', 'date__month').annotate(totals = ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('income')),
    output_field = FloatField())).values_list('date__year', 'date__month', 'totals')):
  if id not in income.keys() and year == now:
  income[id] = list(defaults)
  index = month - 1
  income[id][index] = totals
```

If I set now in the following manner, it works perfectly:

```
now=datetime.datetime.now()
now=now.year
```

But If I set a form in the following manner:

```
#
models

class Timing(models.Model):
  reference_year = models.DateField()

# views

  nows = []
  form = TimingForm(request.POST or None)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
      nows = form.cleaned_data['reference_year']
  nows = nows.year
```

Python gives me the following errors:

`<built-in function id>`

```
income[id][index]=totlas
```

Why??

Comment: could you add at least 2-3 line of error

Comment: You use `if id not in income.keys()`, but you haven't set `id` anywhere.

Comment: As an aside, it's not good practice to use `id` as a variable name, because it clashes with the built-in function id.